# ajax starts getting delayed responses

Tags: jquery, ajax, delay

after the page being open for some time this ajax request gets a lot slower or doesn't work

```
 $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "atuamae.org/send.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
  showmessages()
  //podia-se meter o texto desaparecer suavemente por baixo..
  }  
 });
```

there is also this other function runing:

```
  function showmessages(){
  $("#messages").load('atuamae.org/show-messages-encomendar.php');
   setTimeout('showmessages()',15000);
  }
```

are they interfering with each other?
is data being accumulated somehow?

p.s. for some reason this affects are more significant in chrome than in Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `showmessages()` yourself or make that ajax call which calls it, it starts a new loop of calling `showmessages()` every 15 seconds.

So, if you call that ajax call 10 times, you will end up with 10 timers calling `showmessages()` every 15 seconds.  If you call the ajax call 30 times, you will end up with 30 timers calling `showmessages()` every 15 seconds which means it will be being called every 1/2 second.  Yes, things would slow down a lot.

Do you really means for `showmessages()` to call itself indefinitely every 15 seconds?

Comment: well yes, I would prefer a solution with something like comet, but I tried understanding how it works and it still looks to scary for me, in a few months maybe I'll have another try